# Why does monitor stay on when DPMS is enabled?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, nouveau, dpms

I am running Mint 13 connected to a Dell U2711 monitor via displayport.

When the GDM logon screen is displayed, DPMS does not ever shut down the monitor.

If I logon and run

```
$ xset -q
```

I get

```
... 
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
...
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

If I run

```
$ xset dpms force off
```

The monitor blanks for about two seconds, and then it comes back on again.

I have tried disabling my mouse as [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/301742/dont-let-the-mouse-wake-up-displays-from-standby) suggests with

```
$ xinput --set-prop [id] "Device Enabled" "0"
```

but no luck.

The symptoms are a little different than [this post's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4466/screen-turns-on-automatically-xset-dpms-force-off), and I am not running gnome-power-manager.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my video card and driver information:

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106GL 
[Quadro 2000] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
$ egrep -i " connected" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[1743798.098] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DP-2 connected
$ egrep -i "drivers" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[1743797.880] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[1743797.882] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[1743797.882] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
...
```

I also have:

```
$ grep DPMS /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[2246008.870] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[2246009.091] (II) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
[2246009.113] (==) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS enabled
```

Comment: What exact graphics card model do you have? What driver are you using (free or proprietary)?

Comment: I've added card and driver information.

Comment: Can you please provide your Xorg.conf and it's log file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be your driver. Try using the NVidia driver and see if it fixes the problem. According to this guy, who also had problems with a Dell U2 series monitor said the problem was with the Nouveau drivers: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=130972